# jar and package won't work

Tags: java, android, jar

I'm building a small game application. I've build the whole engine using java and seperated the engine from the logic, and it worked perfectly fine as a console and a swing-UI application.

now I want to migrate it into android and for some reason my emulator crashes each time I try to create any instance from the package I've build.

I added it to the project as a jar file (and added it to my path). afterwards I added the *.java package to the android project and it still crashes.

your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Java is not the same than android (even if they share a lot of things). To begin this, the way the classes are executed is completely different. You should start with an android tutorial.

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: android sdk recognizes the jar file, and its classes (no compling error while writing code). to check what exactly happens I created a button that create the an instance of the game engine when pressed. the moment i press the button i get: the Application HFP has(package) has stopped unexpectadly. please try again

Comment: Can't you see anything on the Android logcat?

Comment: Check the debug section of the link - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

Comment: it writes FATAL EXCEPTION:main. I will check and see what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a million reasons for this. Most likely reasons are:

- You compile your code to Java 7 (you have different class format)
- You use a dependency that is not present in the Android environment

Try to add your *source* to the source folder of your Android project, and let the Android environment compile it to you. Do not use the jar file. That will work for sure.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have tried it, and it's compiling but when I create an instance it crashes

Comment: Try removing the externally compiled jar completely from your project, that may disturb classloading.

Comment: BTW, why should compiling using JAVA 7 would hurt android? should I compile now on wards using JAVA 6?

Comment: `FATAL EXCEPTION:main` hides some other error, for example NullPointerException. See the logcat for it.